# How to Calculate Working Hours including Minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that fetches employee's name, date, working hours, wage and calculate salary based on working hours * wage.

The minutes in working hours that is being calculated are discarded. I only get the value in full hour. Snapshot example:

My main concern is on workingHours and wageAmount

[image]

workingHours is displayed as 5. Here is the time sheet snapshot:

[image]

As you see shift starts at 10:30 AM and ends at 4:00 PM (excluding lunch time), so the actual total hours is 4 and a half not 5.

Here is the query snippet that calculates the hours:

```
   DATEDIFF(HOUR, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) - DATEDIFF(HOUR, lunchStart.timeEntered, lunchEnd.timeEntered) AS workingHours,
```

***MY QUESTION IS:***

**1. How can i calculate working hours accurately with minutes included (discard seconds)?**

Since i will be counting the minutes, i will have to calculate the wage per minute so i will have to put the following code that calculates wage per minute:

```
              ROUND((((DATEDIFF(HOUR, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) - DATEDIFF(HOUR, lunchStart.timeEntered, lunchEnd.timeEntered)) * 60) * (cast(((w.wageAmount/60)-((w.wageAmount/60)%.001)) as decimal (18,3)))), 0) AS "SalaryPerMin",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF(minute, shiftStart.timeEntered, shiftEnd.timeEntered) * 1.0 / 60` instead, to give you the hour as a decimal.

Comment: Great ... I get a value that looks like this:

Comment: 4.514406 ..... I need a simple quick way to truncate the decimal without rounding to one decimal place so the output be as 4.5 ... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Time card stuff is very business rule intensive.  I would consider your architecture before putting all the rules in sp's.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the Hours & Minutes:
CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime) AS DECIMAL)/60